# PHP filetime is not getting updated

Tags: php

I was trying to get last file modified time as a LIVE thing but it is not getting updated...

Running this at PHP cli:

```
<?php
$filename = 'include.php';

while(1){
    sleep(1);
    echo date('H:i:s',filemtime($filename))."\n";
}

?>
```

When I update the file it does not get the last updated time..

Someone know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php), it say

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache()
>   for more details.

So, you have to call [clearstatcache()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) at the end of the while.

Comment: Thanks, gonna double check before ask these things... Such shame.